# How to add custom button in wordpress admin section

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add "one custom button"(Send) in "wordpress admin panel", So i can send information to all users,
But button not showing in my admin panel section,i tried with following code in "functions.php" file,where i am wrong ?

```
add_action('manage_$post_type_posts_custom_column', 'my_custom_column', 10, 2);
$column="Send";

function my_custom_column($column, $post_id) {
  if ($column == $my_column_name) {
    echo '<button>My Button</button>';
  }
  else
  {
      echo '<button>My Button</button>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
add_action( 'manage_post_type_posts_custom_column' , 'my_custom_column', 10, 2 );
function my_custom_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    $my_column_name='NAME-OF-THE-COLUMN';
    switch ( $column ) {
        case $my_column_name:
            echo '<button>My Button</button>';
            break;
    }
}
```

you actually forgot to add/assign $my_column_name to the actual column name you want to insert a button under.